# In SQL how do you join these tables into another one?

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry I'm struggling with something that should be simple.

I have table "Risks_For_Task_1":

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| RiskName     | Mitigation  | RiskLevel    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Risk A       | Mitigate#1  | Medium       |
| Risk B       | Mitigate#2  | Low          |
| Risk C       | Mitigate#3  | High         |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

And a table "Risks_For_Task_2":

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| RiskName     | Mitigation  | RiskLevel    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Risk D       | Mitigate#4  | Low          |
| Risk E       | Mitigate#5  | Low          |
| Risk F       | Mitigate#6  | Medium       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

And a table "Risks_For_Task_3":

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| RiskName     | Mitigation  | RiskLevel    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Risk G       | Mitigate#7  | Medium       |
| Risk H       | Mitigate#8  | High         |
| Risk I       | Mitigate#9  | Medium       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

And a table "Tasks":

```
+--------------+-------------+
| ID           | TaskName    |
+--------------+-------------+
| 1            | Task#1      |
| 2            | Task#2      |
| 3            | Task#3      |
+--------------+-------------+
```

I wish to combine Risks_For_Task_1, Risks_For_Task_2, and Risks_For_Task_3, and put them into an existing table called "Task_Risks" with an extra column referencing the ID from the table Tasks. So the result should look like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| RiskName     | Mitigation  | RiskLevel    | TaskID       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Risk A       | Mitigate#1  | Medium       | 1            |
| Risk B       | Mitigate#2  | Low          | 1            |
| Risk C       | Mitigate#3  | High         | 1            |
| Risk D       | Mitigate#4  | Low          | 2            |
| Risk E       | Mitigate#5  | Low          | 2            |
| Risk F       | Mitigate#6  | Medium       | 2            |
| Risk G       | Mitigate#7  | Medium       | 3            |
| Risk H       | Mitigate#8  | High         | 3            |
| Risk I       | Mitigate#9  | Medium       | 3            |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

This is what I wrote:

```
INSERT INTO Task_Risks (RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, TaskID)
Select RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, TaskID from 
    ((Select RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel from Risks_For_Task_1 
        Full Join 
    Select ID from Tasks where TaskName='Task#1')
    Union All
    (Select RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel from Risks_For_Task_2 
        Full Join 
    Select ID from Tasks where TaskName='Task#2')
    Union All
    (Select RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel from Risks_For_Task_3 
        Full Join 
    Select ID from Tasks where TaskName='Task#3'));
```

Above code gives the error "invalid table name".

Comment: Add a tag for the DB that you use, AND what are the errors?

Comment: It is a good idea that you want to change the broken database model and replace the Risks_For_Task_x tables with only one Task_Risks table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store the risks in separate tables; instead you should have one table with all the risks and an additional task column with a referential constraint to the primary key of the `tasks` table.

However, that appears to be what you have in your `Task_Risks` table.

---

Use a sub-query:

```sql
INSERT INTO Task_Risks (RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, TaskID)
  SELECT RiskName,
         Mitigation,
         RiskLevel,
         (SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE Task = 'Task#1')
  FROM   Risks_For_Task_1 
UNION ALL
  SELECT RiskName,
         Mitigation,
         RiskLevel,
         (SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE Task = 'Task#2')
  FROM   Risks_For_Task_2 
UNION ALL
  SELECT RiskName,
         Mitigation,
         RiskLevel,
         (SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE Task = 'Task#3')
  FROM   Risks_For_Task_3
```

or a join:

```sql
INSERT INTO Task_Risks (RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, TaskID)
  SELECT r.RiskName,
         r.Mitigation,
         r.RiskLevel,
         t.id
  FROM   ( SELECT RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, 'Task#1' AS task
           FROM   Risks_For_Task_1 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, 'Task#2'
           FROM   Risks_For_Task_2 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT RiskName, Mitigation, RiskLevel, 'Task#3'
           FROM   Risks_For_Task_3
         ) r
         INNER JOIN tasks t
         ON (r.task = t.task)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Union All` you have to select all the columns that you want to insert. So in this case, `TaskID` is missing in your select statement.

You can either store the TaskId in a variable and use that in the Select statement or you can use a subquery to select as suggested by @MT0

Comment: I want to use ID from "Tasks" as the value of TaskID